# MySQL trim or get specific set of string using substring locate

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sqlite

I have a column named `cea_no` from my table. But I want only specific string from it. I already tried several methods but it it wont work for me. Do you have any idea how could I achieve this?

Here is my query

```
select id, cea_no, substring(cea_no, 1, locate('/', cea_no)) as x  from xp_guru_listings limit 10;
```

The result

```
+----+-----------------------------+------------------+
| id | cea_no                      | x                |
+----+-----------------------------+------------------+
|  1 | "CEA: R017722B / L3009740K" | "CEA: R017722B / |
|  2 | "CEA: R016023J / L3009793I" | "CEA: R016023J / |
|  3 | "CEA: R011571E / L3002382K" | "CEA: R011571E / |
|  4 | "CEA: R054044J / L3010738A" | "CEA: R054044J / |
|  5 | "CEA: R041180B / L3009250K" | "CEA: R041180B / |
|  6 | "CEA: R030152G / L3008022J" | "CEA: R030152G / |
|  7 | "CEA: R057318G / L3008022J" | "CEA: R057318G / |
|  8 | "CEA: R043256G / L3002382K" | "CEA: R043256G / |
|  9 | "CEA: R026068E / L3002382K" | "CEA: R026068E / |
| 10 | "CEA: R053784I / L3008022J" | "CEA: R053784I / |
+----+-----------------------------+------------------+
```

I only want the `R017722B` part. Removing the `"CEA:` , the second set of strings after the `/`part of the string. How can I do that? Thanks a lot. Im using MySQL xampp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `SUBSTRING_INDEX` here:

```
SELECT
    id,
    cea_no,
    select
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(cea_no, 'CEA: ', -1), ' / ', 1) AS x
FROM xp_guru_listings;
```

To see how this trick works, consider a `cea_no` value of `CEA: R017722B / L3009740K`.  The first call to `SUBSTRING_INDEX` returns `R017722B / L3009740K`, and the second call returns `R017722B`.

Comment: Ohh I see. So i was using the wrong function `substring` . Can you explain more what are their differences?

Comment: `LOCATE` is used to find the position of a substring in a string.  This could be used in conjunction with substring to find the CEA number you want.  But `SUBSTRING_INDEX` sort of incorporates both of these functionalities in one function, and it is what I would use here.

Answer (score 0):

Considering Tim Biegeleisen answer, If you want to update all columns, just edit his code like this:

```
UPDATE xp_guru_listings set cea_no = 
(select SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(cea_no, 'CEA: ', -1), ' / ', 1));
```

In that way, your column `cea_no` will be updated with the value that you want. Cheers!